# Reason why the code doesn't sum the values on the match column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such an issue. I have a column named 'DC (full)' that sometimes has incosistent data such as 'DC01' and later 'DC01 AUX OPS' which should be regarded as 'DC01', I trimmed it and created a separate column as 'DC'. And later created a 'Match' column that is a concat of Item# and DC.

However, for some reason the code doesn't want to sum values of two columns of 'DC01' and 'DC01 AUX OPS' and I need it to have in one row.  Does someone know how it can be fixed?

Code

```
SELECT INVENTLOCATIONID [DC (full)], substring(INVENTLOCATIONID, 1, charindex(' ', INVENTLOCATIONID + ' ')-1) AS 'DC',
concat(ITEMID, substring(INVENTLOCATIONID, 1, charindex(' ', INVENTLOCATIONID + ' ')-1)) AS 'Match',
          ITEMID [ITEM], 
          INVENTSITEID,
       SUM(PHYSICALINVENT) [INVENTORY OH] 
          
          
FROM   [dbo].[vw_RDSInventSumStagingV2]
WHERE  INVENTSITEID = 01
and ITEMID='9780062377029'
GROUP BY INVENTLOCATIONID, ITEMID, INVENTSITEID
HAVING SUM(PHYSICALINVENT) > 0
```

Output

[image]

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Well... you almost have it. Group by `substring(INVENTLOCATIONID, 1, charindex(' ', INVENTLOCATIONID + ' ')-1)` instead of `INVENTLOCATIONID`.

Comment: Please post the "output" as text (not a screen shot) since we can't copy text or write queries against images. Also, please post some sample rows *before* any aggregation.

Comment: @TheImpaler the `dbo` schema for the table name is a strong indicator this is SQL Server. I updated the tags appropriately.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah, I agree. Could be SAP Adaptive as well, though not many people use it anymore.

Comment: @TheImpaler - Ahh, I forgot Sybase used dbo too

Comment: Thanks everyone. What Joel wrote helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *full `INVENTLOCATIONID` column* is used for the `GROUP BY` clause, and therefore `01` and `01 AUX OPS` are *different groups*. If you need them to be the same group, then indicate that in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT substring(INVENTLOCATIONID, 1, charindex(' ', INVENTLOCATIONID + ' ')-1) AS 'DC',
concat(ITEMID, substring(INVENTLOCATIONID, 1, charindex(' ', INVENTLOCATIONID + ' ')-1)) AS 'Match',
          ITEMID [ITEM], 
          INVENTSITEID,
       SUM(PHYSICALINVENT) [INVENTORY OH] 
          
          
FROM   [dbo].[vw_RDSInventSumStagingV2]
WHERE  INVENTSITEID = 01
and ITEMID='9780062377029'
GROUP BY substring(INVENTLOCATIONID, 1, charindex(' ', INVENTLOCATIONID + ' ')-1), ITEMID, INVENTSITEID
HAVING SUM(PHYSICALINVENT) > 0
```

Of course, now you don't see `DC (full)` any more, because those records are rolled up with the larger `DC` group. There could be many different values for the `01` `DC (full)` group in that same record. You can't have it both ways; you must pick either the group or the individual members of the group.